Constant predicted values in LightGBM
I am trying to predict a variable (Y) using LightGBM Regression. However my predicted values are all the same (i.e. constant). Can someone help out in detecting the problem.
data_x = [[2021,5,368.92],[2023,11,356.82],[2022,10,352.49],[2023,5,343.63],[2023,10,324.91],[2022,12,352.02],[2021,6,370.79],[2022,5,386.59],[2019,2,301.56],[2021,4,353.7],[2021,1,303.93],[2021,9,371.94],[2019,4,310.77],[2021,3,345.3],[2020,5,249.63],[2022,4,381.16],[2023,4,363.14],[2019,7,304.19],[2020,7,258.43],[2022,2,412.47],[2022,8,353.43],[2019,6,302.34],[2020,1,319.88],[2022,7,361.66],[2020,9,265.39],[2022,3,408.72],[2022,1,417.47],[2022,6,351.92],[2022,9,344.06],[2022,11,373.75],[2019,9,314.97],[2019,11,324.14],[2023,2,377.23],[2021,11,380.83],[2021,12,403.12],[2023,7,368.73],[2023,1,379.76],[2019,5,295.02],[2023,9,343.78],[2020,4,248.54],[2019,10,314.79],[2019,8,295.92],[2023,3,354.09],[2023,6,357.35],[2021,2,324.31],[2020,3,246.26],[2019,3,295.36],[2020,12,306.27],[2021,8,376.54],[2020,6,258.21],[2023,8,352.35],[2021,7,370.21],[2020,10,259.13],[2020,8,275.66],[2019,12,315.47],[2020,11,301.27],[2021,10,389.23],[2019,1,291.94],[2020,2,302.38]]

df_x = pd.DataFrame(data_x, columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Close'])

data_y = [[1479.42],[1654.53],[1537.76],[1621.22],[1567.62],[1528.39],[1444.63],[1562.17],[1356.81],[1463.48],[1558.9],[1463.96],[1362.03],[1432.7],[1502.46],[1524.71],[1592.68],[1342.74],[1467.48],[1553.66],[1609.19],[1349.1],[1379.39],[1496.12],[1448.08],[1562.96],[1525.25],[1575.06],[1591.15],[1544.66],[1319.9],[1366.73],[1482.72],[1520.73],[1557.03],[1577.37],[1624.74],[1402.05],[1614.94],[1482.28],[1338.88],[1354.6],[1553.65],[1606.36],[1510.78],[1348.05],[1323.39],[1542.95],[1411.64],[1493.44],[1563.53],[1414.8],[1452.67],[1491.7],[1451.43],[1467.23],[1477.13],[1360.29],[1386.48]]

df_y = pd.DataFrame(data_y, columns=['Value'])

X_df_earn_ind_fin_train, X_df_earn_ind_fin_test, y_df_earn_ind_fin_train, y_df_earn_ind_fin_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21)

hyper_params = {
    'task': 'train',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'metric': ['mape', 'auc'],
    'learning_rate': 0.01,
    'feature_fraction': 0.9,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.7,
    'bagging_freq': 10,
    'verbose': 0,
    'verbose_eval': -1,
    "max_depth": 10,
    "num_leaves": 96,  
    "max_bin": 256,
    "num_iterations": 1000,
    "n_estimators": 250
}

gbm = lgm.LGBMRegressor(**hyper_params)
gbm.fit(X_df_earn_ind_fin_train, y_df_earn_ind_fin_train,
        eval_set=[(X_df_earn_ind_fin_test, y_df_earn_ind_fin_test)],
        eval_metric='mape')

y_pred_df_earn_ind_test = gbm.predict(X_df_earn_ind_fin_test)


However my output is just an array of a constant value
y_pred_df_earn_ind_test = 
array([1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863,
       1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863,
       1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863,
       1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863, 1497.21170863,
       1497.21170863, 1497.21170863])


How do I rectify this?

Tree's cannot extrapolate (with some exceptions, i.e. those that use linear regression in the leaves) meaning if you're using them for forecasting you should not use year as a feature - the model won't be able to produce reasonable predictions outside the range of years you used in the training data. If your data has a trend you need to remove it first.

The constant is probably the value for the last year in your training data, assuming you split the data into train/test using some form of time-series split (i.e. latest data is in the test set, earliest in the train set). Also note not doing this is another common ts regression pitfall.

forecasting is the next step. but currently I am splitting the train test randomly within the given dataset so wouldn't the predicted year be within the training dataset already? For e.g. if X_train has years from 2019 to 2023...and predictions are also for values within those same years. I will still try and see how it looks after dropping the 'year' variable. Also I did random split of data (i.e. train/test years are random and not taken like train= initial years and test=later years). Should I split data into serial time buckets?

Also wouldn't trend be an aid in time series forecasting? Like it will help in predicting next month's values based on previous trends. Should I keep the trend or remove it?

You'd want to use the trend, but if you're using a tree based approach you need to remove the trend, predict level and seasonality from the other features and then use add the trend back in (i.e. use a separate linear model for the trend) - i.e. similar to STL decomposition.

I'm not sure though why you're seeing constants "in sample". Try and predict using your training data instead - that'll help identify if it's a problem with the test data or the modelling (the hyperparameters should almost certainly overfit the training data). And yes in general you shouldn't use random split for time series - you'll end up with almost identical (i.e. serially correlated) samples in your test and train set and your test error will be meaningless

Finally LGBM has linear trees (https://medium.com/@alessandrotakeshimorita/linear-trees-in-lightgbm-e147f0f39ec3) which can help with trend. Having said that you don't have many features in your dataset so SARIMAX or LSTM would probably work better (or at least you should add lagged targets as features)

"lagged targets as features" what do you mean by that? do you mean I lag my target (Y variable) by (for e.g.) 2 months and add them as a predictor in X train dataset?

Yeah exactly that.

I've provided an answer below. The comments above about the time-series structure of the problem are interesting, but not the root cause of the problem OP reported. Please review "how to create a minimal, reproducible example" (link) before posting here in the future. You could have made this more likely to generate high-quality answers by providing import statements, listing the versions of lightgbm and scikit-learn, and trying to remove parameters until you found the minimal set that still reproduces the issue.

Short Answer
When the training data contains less than 200 rows, use the following parameters:

min_data_in_leaf = 1
min_data_in_bin = 1

Details
LightGBM has a few important parameters to prevent against overfitting, and the default values of these assume you have at least a few hundred samples.

min_data_in_leaf: minimum number of samples that must fall into a leaf node (default = 20)
min_data_in_bin: minimum number of samples to group together into one histogram "bin" when LightGBM discretizes features (default = 3)

For more details on that, see "Why R2 score is zero in LightGBM?" and "Why does this simple LightGBM classifier perform poorly?".
For a very small dataset like the one in your example (41 rows, 3 columns), those default values might be very limiting, resulting in only a few splits being added per tree.
Consider the following example using exactly the data you provided, with Python 3.11, lightgbm==4.3.0, pandas==2.2.1, and scikit-learn==1.4.1.
import lightgbm as lgb
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_x = [[2021,5,368.92],[2023,11,356.82],[2022,10,352.49],[2023,5,343.63],[2023,10,324.91],[2022,12,352.02],[2021,6,370.79],[2022,5,386.59],[2019,2,301.56],[2021,4,353.7],[2021,1,303.93],[2021,9,371.94],[2019,4,310.77],[2021,3,345.3],[2020,5,249.63],[2022,4,381.16],[2023,4,363.14],[2019,7,304.19],[2020,7,258.43],[2022,2,412.47],[2022,8,353.43],[2019,6,302.34],[2020,1,319.88],[2022,7,361.66],[2020,9,265.39],[2022,3,408.72],[2022,1,417.47],[2022,6,351.92],[2022,9,344.06],[2022,11,373.75],[2019,9,314.97],[2019,11,324.14],[2023,2,377.23],[2021,11,380.83],[2021,12,403.12],[2023,7,368.73],[2023,1,379.76],[2019,5,295.02],[2023,9,343.78],[2020,4,248.54],[2019,10,314.79],[2019,8,295.92],[2023,3,354.09],[2023,6,357.35],[2021,2,324.31],[2020,3,246.26],[2019,3,295.36],[2020,12,306.27],[2021,8,376.54],[2020,6,258.21],[2023,8,352.35],[2021,7,370.21],[2020,10,259.13],[2020,8,275.66],[2019,12,315.47],[2020,11,301.27],[2021,10,389.23],[2019,1,291.94],[2020,2,302.38]]

df_x = pd.DataFrame(data_x, columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Close'])

data_y = [[1479.42],[1654.53],[1537.76],[1621.22],[1567.62],[1528.39],[1444.63],[1562.17],[1356.81],[1463.48],[1558.9],[1463.96],[1362.03],[1432.7],[1502.46],[1524.71],[1592.68],[1342.74],[1467.48],[1553.66],[1609.19],[1349.1],[1379.39],[1496.12],[1448.08],[1562.96],[1525.25],[1575.06],[1591.15],[1544.66],[1319.9],[1366.73],[1482.72],[1520.73],[1557.03],[1577.37],[1624.74],[1402.05],[1614.94],[1482.28],[1338.88],[1354.6],[1553.65],[1606.36],[1510.78],[1348.05],[1323.39],[1542.95],[1411.64],[1493.44],[1563.53],[1414.8],[1452.67],[1491.7],[1451.43],[1467.23],[1477.13],[1360.29],[1386.48]]

df_y = pd.DataFrame(data_y, columns=['Value'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df_x,
    df_y,
    test_size=0.3,
    random_state=21
)

params = {
    "num_iterations": 10,
    "objective": "regression",
    "min_data_in_leaf": 1,
    "min_data_in_bin": 1,
    "verbose": 0,
}

# train
gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**params)
gbm.fit(X_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
        eval_metric='mape')

# predict
preds = gbm.predict(X_test)
print(preds)

That produces predictions with some variation.
[1514.86588126 1557.1389268  1423.54076682 1514.86588126 1488.24836945
 1541.52116271 1555.63537413 1393.69927646 1404.48244093 1465.1569698
 1404.48244093 1404.48244093 1514.86588126 1440.95713788 1535.84165832
 1482.58308126 1471.96999117 1504.50006758]

And the following scores on the test set
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, r2_score

mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds)
# 45.212

r2_score(y_test, preds)
# 0.47

Some other notes related to the original question:

num_iterations and n_estimators are aliases for each other... they mean exactly the same thing. Just use one of them. (LightGBM docs)
"auc" is a classification metric... it isn't appropriate for regression problems (LightGBM docs)
tas" is only for the LightGBM CLI. It doesn't affect the Python package at all. Omit it. (LightGBM docs)
In the scikit-learn estimators for LightGBM, omit metric from params and just pass the eval_metric keyword arguments to .fit()

